# RoR: deep clone: how do I also clone models that reference the one I'm cloning? - as in clone models via the has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deep-copy

My Code:

```
  class  ActiveRecord::Base  
      def clone!(options = {})
        defaults = {:except => [:updated_at, :cerated_at, :id], :shallow => []}
        options = defaults.merge(options)

        skip_attributes = options[:except] or false #attributes not to clone at all
        shallow_attributes = options[:shallow] or false # non-recursivly cloned attributes
        options[:except] << self.class.to_s.foreign_key # add current class to exceptions to prevent infinite loop

        new_model = self.class.new

        self.attributes.each_pair do |attribute, value|
          skip_attribute = (skip_attributes ? skip_attributes.map{|a| a.to_s}.include?(attribute) : false)
          next if skip_attribute

          shallow_copy = (shallow_attributes ? shallow_attributes.map{|s| s.to_s}.include?(attribute) : false)

          if attribute =~ /_id\z/ and (not shallow_copy)
            # assume reference to a different object
            model_table_name = attribute.gsub(/_id\z/, "")
            model_name = model_table_name.camelize

            referenced_object = model_name.constantize.find(value).clone!(options)
            puts attribute.inspect
            puts referenced_object.inspect
            new_model.send("#{attribute}=", referenced_object[:id])
          else
            new_model.send("#{attribute}=", value) 
          end
        end

        new_model.save!
      end
    end
```

So, one way to call the method is to do:

b = MyObject.find(432).clone!({:shallow => [:account_id, :user_id, :ext_integration_id, :category_id], :except => [:closed_comment_id]})

The issue is MyObject HAS MANY OtherObjects, so MyObject itsself doesn't directly reference the OtherObjects, because the OtherObjects have the foreign key to MyObject.

How do I find out what the names of the models are that have this relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gem does the trick:

https://github.com/DerNalia/deep_cloning

currently has the most features of any of the deep_cloning gems.

Tested on 1.8.7 with Rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is completely applicable because I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to copy and what you don't, but...

You may get some good use out of the [Amoeba gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/amoeba) for ActiveRecord 3.2.

It supports easy and automatic recursive duplication of `has_one`, `has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations, field preprocessing and a highly flexible and powerful configuration DSL that can be applied both to the model and on the fly.

be sure to check out the [Amoeba Documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/amoeba/frames) but usage is pretty easy...

just

```
gem install amoeba
```

or add

```
gem 'amoeba'
```

to your Gemfile

then add the amoeba block to your model and run the `dup` method as usual

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  amoeba do
    enable
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end

class PostsController < ActionController
  def some_method
    my_post = Post.find(params[:id])
    new_post = my_post.dup
    new_post.save
  end
end
```

Your new post should have all the tags that were originally associated with it, and all the comments should be duplicated as well. You can disable the duplication of various records through the DSL, which you can read about in the documentation, but for example, if you wanted to keep the tags, but not the comments you could do something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  amoeba do
    include_field :comments
  end
end
```

this should result in re-associating the new post with the same tags as the old post, but without duplicating the comments.

Amoeba will also automatically recurse in to child records if you enable them

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  amoeba do
    enable
  end
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :ratings

  amoeba do
    enable
  end
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the level of detail and examples in your post! I've added this to our ticket tracker for when we upgrade to rails 3. It's certainly a lot more rails-y feeling than the gem we are currently using: https://github.com/DerNalia/deep_cloning (just extends ActiveRecord::Base)